# How to write a directory traversing program which can feedback the total number of subdirectories, files, etc?

Tags: go, goroutine

Try to write a directory traversing program by goroutine and channel, but unable to get the needed results. Expect to get the number of total sub-directory, files count. But when I run the code below, it will stuck in "dirCount <-1". PS: is that possible to write such a program with infinite depth traversing

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type DirectoryItem struct {
    Name  string `json:"name,omitemty"`
    IsDir bool   `json:"isDir,omitempty"`
    Size  int64  `json:"size,omitempty"`
}

type DirectoryInfo struct {
    Path string          `json:"path,omitemty"`
    Dirs []DirectoryItem `json:"dirs,omitempty"`
}

var dirItems []DirectoryItem
var dirInfo DirectoryInfo

func GetOneDirItems(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fpath := "E:\\"

    query := req.URL.Query()
    path := query["path"][0]

    fpath = fpath + path

    dirInfo, _ := CheckEachItem(fpath)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(dirInfo)
}

func CheckEachItem(dirPath string) (directory DirectoryInfo, err error) {
    var items []DirectoryItem

    dir, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dirPath)

    if err != nil {
        return directory, err
    }

    for _, fi := range dir {
        if fi.IsDir() {
            items = append(items, DirectoryItem{Name: fi.Name(), IsDir: true, Size: 0})

        } else {
            items = append(items, DirectoryItem{Name: fi.Name(), IsDir: false, Size: fi.Size()})
        }
    }
    directory = DirectoryInfo{Path: dirPath, Dirs: items}

    return directory, nil
}

func CalcDirInfo(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    query := req.URL.Query()

    path := query["path"][0]

    url := "http://localhost:8090/api/GetOneDirItems?path="

    url += path

    dirCount := make(chan int)
    fileCount := make(chan int)

    go Recr(url, dirCount, fileCount)

    //
    dirTotalCount := 0

    for i := range dirCount {
        dirTotalCount += i
    }

    fmt.Println(dirTotalCount)

}

func Recr(url string, dirCount chan int, fileCount chan int) {

    fmt.Println(url)

    resp, _ := http.Get(url)

    dirInfo = DirectoryInfo{}

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &dirInfo)

    for _, itm := range dirInfo.Dirs {
        fmt.Println("--")
        if itm.IsDir {
            newUrl := url + "/" + itm.Name

            //// looks like stuck in here
            dirCount <- 1
            go Recr(newUrl, dirCount, fileCount)
        } else {
            fileCount <- 1
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    //#1 func one:
    //result sample:
    //{"path":"E:\\code","dirs":[{"name":"A","isDir":true},{"name":"B","isDir":false}]}
    router.HandleFunc("/api/GetOneDirItems", GetOneDirItems).Methods("GET")

    //#2 2nd api to invoke 1st api recursively
    //expected result
    //{"path":"E:\\code","dirCount":2, "fileCount":3]}
    router.HandleFunc("/api/GetDirInfo", CalcDirInfo).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8090", router))

}
```

find some code example but not feedback the right number...

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

//!+1
var done = make(chan struct{})

func cancelled() bool {
    select {
    case <-done:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

//!-1

type DirectoryItem struct {
    Name  string `json:"name,omitemty"`
    IsDir bool   `json:"isDir,omitempty"`
    Size  int64  `json:"size,omitempty"`
}

type DirectoryInfo struct {
    Path string          `json:"path,omitemty"`
    Dirs []DirectoryItem `json:"dirs,omitempty"`
}

var dirItems []DirectoryItem
var dirInfo DirectoryInfo

func GetOneDirItems(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fpath := "E:\\"

    query := req.URL.Query()
    path := query["path"][0]

    fpath = fpath + path

    dirInfo, _ := CheckEachItem(fpath)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(dirInfo)
}

func CheckEachItem(dirPath string) (directory DirectoryInfo, err error) {
    var items []DirectoryItem

    dir, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dirPath)

    if err != nil {
        return directory, err
    }

    for _, fi := range dir {
        if fi.IsDir() {
            items = append(items, DirectoryItem{Name: fi.Name(), IsDir: true, Size: 0})

        } else {
            items = append(items, DirectoryItem{Name: fi.Name(), IsDir: false, Size: fi.Size()})
        }
    }
    directory = DirectoryInfo{Path: dirPath, Dirs: items}

    return directory, nil
}

func CalcDirInfo(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    query := req.URL.Query()

    path := query["path"][0]

    url := "http://localhost:8090/api/GetOneDirItems?path="

    url += path

    fpath := "E:\\"

    fpath = fpath + path

    dirInfo, _ := CheckEachItem(fpath)

    fileSizes := make(chan int64)
    dirCount := make(chan int, 100)
    var n sync.WaitGroup
    for _, item := range dirInfo.Dirs {

        n.Add(1)
        url = url + "/" + item.Name
        go Recr(url, &n, dirCount, fileSizes)
    }
    go func() {
        n.Wait()
        close(fileSizes)
        close(dirCount)
    }()

    // Print the results periodically.
    // tick := time.Tick(500 * time.Millisecond)
    var nfiles, ndirs, nbytes int64
loop:
    //!+3
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            // Drain fileSizes to allow existing goroutines to finish.
            for range fileSizes {
                // Do nothing.
            }

            return
        case size, ok := <-fileSizes:
            // ...
            //!-3
            if !ok {
                break loop // fileSizes was closed
            }
            nfiles++
            nbytes += size

        case _, ok := <-dirCount:
            // ...
            //!-3
            if !ok {
                break loop // dirCount was closed
            }
            ndirs++

            // case <-tick:
            // printDiskUsage(nfiles, ndirs, nbytes)
        }
    }
    printDiskUsage(nfiles, ndirs, nbytes) // final totals

}

func Recr(url string, n *sync.WaitGroup, dirCount chan<- int, fileSizes chan<- int64) {

    defer n.Done()

    resp, _ := http.Get(url)

    dirInfo = DirectoryInfo{}

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &dirInfo)

    for _, itm := range dirInfo.Dirs {

        if itm.IsDir {
            dirCount <- 1
            n.Add(1)

            newUrl := url + "/" + itm.Name

            go Recr(newUrl, n, dirCount, fileSizes)
        } else {
            fileSizes <- itm.Size
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    // Determine the initial directories.
    roots := os.Args[1:]
    if len(roots) == 0 {
        roots = []string{"."}
    }

    // API Services
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.HandleFunc("/api/GetOneDirItems", GetOneDirItems).Methods("GET")

    router.HandleFunc("/api/GetDirInfo", CalcDirInfo).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8090", router))
}

func printDiskUsage(nfiles, ndirs, nbytes int64) {
    fmt.Printf("%d files  %.1f GB   %d dirs\n", nfiles, float64(nbytes)/1e9, ndirs)
}

// walkDir recursively walks the file tree rooted at dir
// and sends the size of each found file on fileSizes.
//!+4
func walkDir(dir string, n *sync.WaitGroup, fileSizes chan<- int64, dirCount chan<- int) {
    defer n.Done()
    if cancelled() {
        return
    }
    for _, entry := range dirents(dir) {
        // ...
        //!-4
        if entry.IsDir() {
            dirCount <- 1
            n.Add(1)
            subdir := filepath.Join(dir, entry.Name())
            go walkDir(subdir, n, fileSizes, dirCount)
        } else {
            fileSizes <- entry.Size()
        }
        //!+4
    }
}

//!-4

var sema = make(chan struct{}, 20) // concurrency-limiting counting semaphore

// dirents returns the entries of directory dir.
//!+5
func dirents(dir string) []os.FileInfo {
    select {
    case sema <- struct{}{}: // acquire token
    case <-done:
        return nil // cancelled
    }
    defer func() { <-sema }() // release token

    // ...read directory...
    //!-5

    f, err := os.Open(dir)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "du: %v\n", err)
        return nil
    }
    defer f.Close()

    entries, err := f.Readdir(0) // 0 => no limit; read all entries
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "du: %v\n", err)
        // Don't return: Readdir may return partial results.
    }
    return entries
}
```

Comment: It's strictly io-bound, you don't need goroutines here.

Comment: Yes, don't complicate matters with concurrency. You "gain" all the problems and none of the benefits in this case.

Comment: @zerkms yes. but this is actually a testing code, not real one. I just want to understand why the code unable to return the expected results by goroutine and recursively invoke method, to traversing infinite depth directories. Can u help:)

Comment: @seesharper yes, I agree.:)  actually it's an interview question, need me to finish it with 5 goroutine and fetch the results...

Comment: Have you tried adding length to your channels so they don't over-fill? `dirCount := make(chan int), 10)`? Also remember to close your channels when done.

Comment: ya with make(chan int, 10) it won't stuck , but still unable to fetch the final amount in the `CalcDirInfo` method.

Comment: Can I ask why you call the server API inside CalcDirInfo rather than simply calling the method to read the directory? It seems very indirect and inefficient.

Comment: actually i'm afraid it' just two interview quetions.. the first is to build a restful api to feedback each item of one specific path(not recursively), and each item will mark its type as dir or not, then second rest api need to invoke the first on recursively to traversing the specific folder and feedback dir/file counting and total file size.

Comment: @seesharper I found some example code in : http://www.programmersought.com/article/57777487/
looks like it's a same way, but it's just kick off the first invoke under the main method, not a restful api func, when I move the code to my api , it's running but not feedback the correct response.

Comment: Please see answer - hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the your program has no way of ending. Basically whenever the code recurses into another directory, you need to count that, and then when it finishes processing the directory, you need to push 1 to a `done` channel. When the count of directories recursed into == the number done, you can exit the channel select (that's the other missing part):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type DirectoryItem struct {
    Name  string `json:"name,omitemty"`
    IsDir bool   `json:"isDir,omitempty"`
    Size  int64  `json:"size,omitempty"`
}

type DirectoryInfo struct {
    Path string          `json:"path,omitemty"`
    Dirs []DirectoryItem `json:"dirs,omitempty"`
}

var dirItems []DirectoryItem
var dirInfo DirectoryInfo

func GetOneDirItems(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fpath := "E:\\"

    query := req.URL.Query()
    path := query["path"][0]

    fpath = fpath + path

    dirInfo, err := CheckEachItem(fpath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(dirInfo)
}

func CheckEachItem(dirPath string) (directory DirectoryInfo, err error) {
    var items []DirectoryItem

    dir, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dirPath)

    if err != nil {
        return directory, err
    }

    for _, fi := range dir {
        if fi.IsDir() {
            items = append(items, DirectoryItem{Name: fi.Name(), IsDir: true, Size: 0})

        } else {
            items = append(items, DirectoryItem{Name: fi.Name(), IsDir: false, Size: fi.Size()})
        }
    }
    directory = DirectoryInfo{Path: dirPath, Dirs: items}

    return directory, nil
}

func CalcDirInfo(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    query := req.URL.Query()

    path := query["path"][0]

    url := "http://localhost:8090/api/GetOneDirItems?path="

    url += path

    dirCount := make(chan int, 10)
    fileCount := make(chan int, 10)
    doneCount := make(chan int, 10)

    go Recr(url, dirCount, fileCount, doneCount)

    //
    dirTotalCount := 0
    doneTotalCount := 0
out:
    for {
        select {
        case dir := <-dirCount:
            dirTotalCount += dir
            fmt.Printf("dirTotalCount=%d\n", dirTotalCount)
        case <-fileCount:
        case done := <-doneCount:
            doneTotalCount += done
            fmt.Printf("doneTotalCount=%d dirTotalCount=%d\n", doneTotalCount, dirTotalCount)
            if doneTotalCount == dirTotalCount+1 { // need -1 because of the root dir, which is not counted as a subdirectory
                break out
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("ALL DONE")
    fmt.Printf("TOTAL=%d\n", dirTotalCount)

}

func Recr(url string, dirCount chan int, fileCount chan int, doneCount chan int) {

    // fmt.Printf("url=%s\n", url)

    resp, _ := http.Get(url)

    dirInfo = DirectoryInfo{}

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &dirInfo)
    // fmt.Printf("dirInfo=%+v body=%s", dirInfo, string(body))

    for _, itm := range dirInfo.Dirs {
        if itm.IsDir {
            newUrl := url + "/" + itm.Name

            //// looks like stuck in here
            // fmt.Printf("pushing one dir from %s\n", url)
            dirCount <- 1
            go Recr(newUrl, dirCount, fileCount, doneCount)
        } else {
            // fmt.Println("pushing one file")
            fileCount <- 1
        }
    }
    doneCount <- 1
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    //#1 func one:
    //result sample:
    //{"path":"E:\\code","dirs":[{"name":"A","isDir":true},{"name":"B","isDir":false}]}
    router.HandleFunc("/api/GetOneDirItems", GetOneDirItems).Methods("GET")

    //#2 2nd api to invoke 1st api recursively
    //expected result
    //{"path":"E:\\code","dirCount":2, "fileCount":3]}
    router.HandleFunc("/api/GetDirInfo", CalcDirInfo).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8090", router))

}
```

Comment: hmmm, that's right:) @seesharper thank you so much!!